# preferredLayoutAttributesFitting not called when invalidating collection view layout with context in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios13

I have the UICollectionView with the flow layout where estimated size is set to `automaticSize`.

`layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`

I have UITextView inputs in the cells and my aim is to have self-sizing cells. So, on every text change in the cell input, I am invalidating the changed cell in layout with the context.

```
let context = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext()
context.invalidateFlowLayoutAttributes = false
context.invalidateItems(at: [indexPath])
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)
```

In order to get correct cell height, I am overriding `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` in the cells and calculating the height dynamically. It works quite fine on iOS 12, `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)` forces `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` to be called. But on iOS 13, it is not called, unless I scroll the collection view.

I could not find anything changed in iOS 13 for `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext`, any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, no luck. We had to redesign the screen a bit to get rid of self-sizing UITextView.